# Data does not save and not displaying any error - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The data doesn't save without prompting any errors in my code

Here is my code in my Controller

```
function saveDebit(){
$jevseries=$this->input->post('series');
$account='debit';
$count='1';
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>'); 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('accountName', 'Account Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('amountDebit', 'Amount', 'required|numeric');

$this->formValidation();
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->entryAccount($jevseries);
        } else {
          $debitData = array(
            'Series' => $jevseries,
            'AccountCode' => $this->input->post('accountName'),
            'Account' => $account,
            'Amount' => $this->input->post('amountDebit'),
            'Count' => $count);

      $this->Jev_model->entryDebit($debitData);
    }
```

}

Model

```
 function entryDebit($debitData){
    $this->db->insert('generalaccount', $debitData);
}
```

This is my View

```
<?php echo form_open('Jev/saveDebit'); ?>
        <table class="jev_entry" id="jev_entry">
            <tr>
                <td>Debit</td>
                <?php echo form_hidden('series', $series);?>
                <td><?php
                 $account_array = array();
                 foreach($accountNames as $account ){
                     $account_array []= $account->accountName;
                 }

                 echo form_dropdown('accountName',  $account_array,'', 'class="form-control"');

                 ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount</td>
                <td><?php  echo form_input('amountDebit','', 'class="form-control"');?><div class="error"><?php echo form_error('amountDebit'); ?></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo '<center>'. form_submit('submit','Save').'</center>'; ?> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I don't know where is the error in this lines.. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us the form?

Comment: I already updated my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay i have found out what is wrong, The form_input of codeigniter only gives the form with a label. It does not give a name therefore we cannot post it since it doesn't have a name. Do this :)

```
$data = array(
        'name'          => 'username',
        'id'            => 'username',
        'value'         => 'johndoe',
        'maxlength'     => '100',
        'size'          => '50',
        'style'         => 'width:50%'
);

echo form_input($data);
```

It's like that and we post the name. Of course you can remove some parameters. More info in the form helper user guide in codeigniter :)

**Godluck meyt**

Comment: Glad to help, Thanks for the check and upvote!! :) @IreneBaluis

Comment: I already solved my problem. It's my mistake, i copied and pasted my code from my other function and pasted in my new function.

$this->formValidation();

Comment: Oh good to know you already solved it. Goodluck in coding more!!